# Order by list using count c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of items

> row_id,   Items
>
> 12134,    Item X
>
> 13243,    Item Y

is that possible in c# to autogenerate the row_id based on list items? SO instead of having 12134 and 13243 the output of the list would be like

> row_id,   Items
>
> 1,   Item X
>
> 2,   Item Y

Comment: use a for loop and give the index + the Item as output

Comment: Why you are not using a Auto generated column in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var source = new List<Item> {new Item(12134, "Item X"), new Item(13243, "Item Y")};
var dest = source.OrderBy(item => item.row_id).Select((item, index) => new Item(index + 1, item.Items)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pair up list items with their list position by using an override of `Select` which takes an `(index, item)` pair:

```
var itemsWithIndex = myList
    // If you would like to change the order of auto-generated IDs,
    // change the expression inside OrderBy; This step is optional.
    .OrderBy(item => <some-expression>)
    .Select((item, index) => new { Item=item, NewId=index+1});
```

Now you can use item's index as you see fit: to display it, to set it back into the item, and so on:

```
foreach (var pair in itemsWithIndex) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", pair.Index, pair.Item.Items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list, loop over the items and set the ID of each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        items[i].RowId = i + 1;
    }
```

This is assuming your item has a property called RowId. This is simpler and does not require the use of LINQ which you may not understand.